# Why the last element in istringstream doesn't disappear in my code?

Tags: c++

I am writing a calculator program in c++ , and I met two problems .

1. After I calculate 1 calculation questions , I only need to  press enter ,then the program will output the last number in the previous calculation .
2. There are some incorrect answer , like  " 7 / 9 / 10 * 1 * 4 / 6 - 3 * 9 - 8 - 7 " , the output should be -41.95 , but my answer is -11.95 .And I can't find what's wrong with my code.

The cin problem has been fixed when I use if(cin.get()!='\n')break;

And At the bottom there is a correct code of others .

---

#### my code use istringstream

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<stack>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int  priority(char op) {
    if (op == '+' || op == '-') return 1;
    else return 2;
}
double calculate(double x, double y, char c)
{
    if (c == '+') return x + y;
    if (c == '-') return x - y;
    if (c == '*')return x * y;
    return x / y;
}
int main() {
    int n;
    char op;
    stack<double> nums;
    stack<char> ops;
    string a;
    int count = 0;
    while (getline(cin, a)) {
        count++;
        int allNum = 0;
        int allzero = 0;
        allNum++;
        istringstream b(a);
        b >> n;
        if (n == 0) allzero++;
        nums.push(n);
        while (b >> op >> n) {
            if (op == '\n') break;
            allNum++;
            if (n == 0) allzero++;
            if (!ops.empty() && priority(op) <= priority(ops.top())) {
                double y = nums.top();
                nums.pop();
                double x = nums.top();
                nums.pop();
                char tem = ops.top();
                ops.pop();
                double new_num = calculate(x, y, tem);
                nums.push(new_num);
            }
            ops.push(op);
            nums.push(n);
        }
        while (!ops.empty()) {
            double y = nums.top();
            nums.pop();
            double x = nums.top();
            nums.pop();
            char tem = ops.top();
            ops.pop();
            double new_num = calculate(x, y, tem);
            nums.push(new_num);
        }
        if (allzero != allNum) cout<< fixed << setprecision(2) << nums.top() << endl;
        b.clear();
        nums.pop();
    }
}
```

#### this is the code I find on the internet

I learned the method from here , the biggest differentenss is that he use C ,and I use C++ .But his result is right .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

int P(char c)
{
    if (c == '+' || c == '-') return 1;
    return 2;
}

double Ans(double x, double y, char c)
{
    if (c == '+') return x + y;
    if (c == '-') return x - y;
    if (c == '*')return x*y;
    return x / y;

}
int main() {
    int n;
    while (scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF)
    {
        char c = getchar();
        if (c=='\n'&&n == 0)break;
        stack<char> op;
        stack<double>num;
        num.push(n);
        while (true)
        {
            scanf("%c %d", &c, &n);
            char k = getchar();
            while (!op.empty()&&P(c)<=P(op.top()))
            {
                char t = op.top();
                op.pop();
                double y = num.top();
                num.pop();
                double x = num.top();
                num.pop();
                double ans = Ans(x, y, t);
                num.push(ans);
            }
            op.push(c);
            num.push(n);
            if (k == '\n')break;

        }
        while (!op.empty())
        {
            char t = op.top();
            op.pop();
            double y = num.top();
            num.pop();
            double x = num.top();
            num.pop();
            double ans = Ans(x, y, t);
            num.push(ans);
        }
        printf("%.2f\n", num.top());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have some code with cin that doesn't work, post code with cin that doesn't work. Don't post code with istringstream and say "but if I use cin here, it doesn't work".

Comment: The condition `op == '\n'` is never true, which doesn't matter in the first code since you're reading "linewise".

Comment: Here's a much simpler test case for you: `0 - 2 * 2 - 4`.

Comment: When you use `cin >> ...`, newlines are treated exactly like spaces. Thsat is, completely skipped. So you may want to use a different expression terminator like `;` or `=`. If you want newlines, just use the `getline` (that is, stick with the first version).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation , could you explain to me why the fisrt element is always in the   istringstream ？